# How do I access a variable in views.py using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, view

## edit

When I write print request.POST['video'], nothing gets printed in the console even through there is a value for 'video'. Am I incorrectly getting the wrong value in the javascript? I am trying to get the 'video34' (the value in the hidden field) to show up.

## original

I am trying to POST data using jQuery/AJAX in Django and am having trouble.  How do I access the 'video' variable in the views.py?  When I write 'print video' in views.py, I get an error in the console saying POST /edit_favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10113.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def edit_favorites(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

## urlconf:

```
url(r'^edit_favorites/', 'edit_favorites'),
```

## html:

```
<form method='post' id ='test'>
     <input type="hidden" value="video34" />
    <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
    
    <div id = 'message'>Initial text</div>
        
</form>
```

## javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#test").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/edit_favorites/",
                 data: {
                        'video': $('#test').val() // from form
                        },
                 success: function(){
                     $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>") 
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });
       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in `request.POST['video']`, just like in a normal POST.

Comment: When I write print request.POST['video'], nothing gets printed in the console even through there is a value for 'video'.  Am I incorrectly getting the wrong value in the javascript? I am trying to get the 'video34' to show up.

Comment: Yes. `#test` refers to the form, and the form doesn't have a `val()`. You should give your field an `id` and use that. Note that you should also always give your fields a `name`, otherwise you won't be able to submit them normally.

Comment: uses $('#test').serialize() to see all of the form data across the wire. like Daniel said, forms do not have a val(), so your sending nothing

Answer (score 2):

In the message you got in the console `POST /edit_favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10113`, the "500" is the key.  It means there's an error in your server code, most likely.  In this case you're trying to 'print' a nonexistent variable.  I'm surprised in fact that you don't see a traceback for a `NameError` somewhere.

I'm not a Django user so maybe someone else can chime in with a better recommendation, but according to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) all the post arguments are in `request.POST` which is a dict-like object.

I'd suggest checking:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'video' in request.POST:
        video = request.POST['video']
        # Do stuff, etc...
    else:
        # Raise an error
```

That's on the server side.  In your HTML you also need to give names to all your form input fields.  For example `<input name="video" type="hidden" value="video32" />` or the like.  You may wish to read up more on HTML form posting.

Comment: When I write print request.POST['video'], nothing gets printed in the console even through there is a value for 'video'.  Am I incorrectly getting the wrong value in the javascript?  I am trying to get the 'video34' to show up.

Comment: In your case your HTML is also missing a 'name' attribute for the form input field.